# how do I properly position & scale these elements in CSS?

Tags: html, css, position, scale, glyphicons

I've been able to properly position & scale a few elements in my webpage using html & css, however due to the rules of positioning, I've gotten stuck on how to continue this action with two more elements.

The chevron icon in the picture must be below the last paragraph entitled "scroll down", & I also want it to scale with the screen size as I have been successfully able to do with the other text/elements as you can see:

[image]

here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>myWebpage</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="pencil.ico" />

    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css"rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="main-sanctuary.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>
      <header>
        <h1>Hellloooooooooooooo!</h1>
        <p id="first-p">Welcome All!<br>Make Yourself at home.</p>
        <p id="secondary-p">Scroll down.</p>
        <button id="logBtn">Log In</button>
        <button id="signBtn">Sign Up</button>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-4x"></i>

      </header>
    </body>
 </html>
```

and here is the css:

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

body,html {
  height: 100%;
  background: honeydew;
}
/* Header*/
header {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/assests/books-apple.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
}
h1 {
  color: honeydew;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  font-size : 7.5vw;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#first-p {
  color: honeydew;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size : 3.5vw;
  margin-bottom: 50px;

}
#secondary-p {
  position: inherit;
  color: #FFD700;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size : 2vw;
  margin-bottom: -90px;

}
.fa {
  color: #FFD700;

}
```

So how do I properly position the `.fa` under `#secondary-p` on my webpage & scale it as well?

Comment: You could use `<p id="secondary-p">Scroll down.<i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-4x"></i></p>` and position the `chevron` icon `absolute` to the `secondary-p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `margin-bottom : -90px;` from `#secondary-p`, this will make Cheveron Icon go below *Scroll Down* (`#sencondary-p`).

And for scaling the Cheveron Icon, add `font-size` to it with a value in `vw`. Like This :-

```
.fa{
  color : #FFD700;
  font-size : 4vw;
}
```

Demo [is here.](http://jsbin.com/quriqa/edit?html,css,output)

**Update**

For shifting them a little bit down, wrap the `.fa` element and the `#sencondary-p` element inside a `div` and give that `div` some `margin-top`. Like this :-

*HTML* :-

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <p id="sencondary-p">Scroll Down</p>
  <i class = "fa fa-chevron-down fa-4x"></i>
</div>
```

*CSS* :-

```
#wrapper{
  margin-top : 100px; /*Increase the value to shift more down*/
}
```

See the updated demo [here.](http://jsbin.com/wujeci/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Great! However all the elements are a little to high for me, how do I move them down a little without breaking the code?

Comment: @MikeStrong Very Sorry for late reply. I've updated my answer. I hope it helps you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Put the chevron inside a div and set the div's position. (Use position: static, which will keep the position consistent.)